Understanding the shape of np.apply_along_axis output
I have a question regarding output dimensions of np.apply_along_axis.
In the first case values of x for the lambda function are [1 2], [1 3], [1 4] and they have shape (2,) since we split across axis=0. Each output of the lambda function has shape (2,2):
import numpy as np

out = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: x + np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]]),
    axis=0,
    arr=np.asarray([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
)

print(out.shape)
# (2, 2, 3)

print(out)
# [[[2 2 2]
#   [4 5 6]]
#  [[4 4 4]
#   [6 7 8]]]

In the second case values of x for the lambda function are [1], [2], [3] and they have shape (1,) since we split across axis=1. Each output of the lambda function has shape (2,2):
import numpy as np

out = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: x + np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]]),
    axis=1,
    arr=np.asarray([[1,2,3]]).T
)

print(out.shape)
# (3, 2, 2)

print(out)
# [[[2 3]
#   [4 5]]
#  [[3 4]
#   [5 6]]
#  [[4 5]
#   [6 7]]]

Can you please explain why in the first case the output has shape (2,2,3) and in the second case its shape is (3,2,2) given that the output from lambda function has the same shape?

This apply... is basically an iterator.  It iterates on all axes except the designated one, and applies the function to 'resulting' 1d arrays.
Your lambda, as a function with prints:
In [26]: def foo(x): 
    ...:     x1 = x + np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]])
    ...:     print(x,x1)
    ...:     return x1
    ...:     

In [27]: out = np.apply_along_axis(
    ...:     func1d=foo,
    ...:     axis=0,
    ...:     arr=np.asarray([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
    ...: )
[1 2] [[2 4]
 [4 6]]
[1 3] [[2 5]
 [4 7]]
[1 4] [[2 6]
 [4 8]]

So it's doing foo(x) for each column of the array.  The column is (2,).  Add that to a (2,2), and the result is a (2,2).
That's the same as list comprehension:
In [28]: arr= np.asarray([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])    
In [29]: [foo(arr[:,i]) for i in range(3)]
[1 2] [[2 4]
 [4 6]]
[1 3] [[2 5]
 [4 7]]
[1 4] [[2 6]
 [4 8]]
Out[29]: 
[array([[2, 4],
        [4, 6]]),
 array([[2, 5],
        [4, 7]]),
 array([[2, 6],
        [4, 8]])]

And joining those 3 (2,2) along a new trailing axis:
In [34]: np.stack([foo(arr[:,i]) for i in range(3)], axis=2).shape
[1 2] [[2 4]
 [4 6]]
[1 3] [[2 5]
 [4 7]]
[1 4] [[2 6]
 [4 8]]
Out[34]: (2, 2, 3)

apply... actually does a trial run, which produces a (2,2).  So it makes a np.zeros((2,2,3)) to hold the results.
apply... is not a speed tool.  It's an iterator.  For 2d like this it isn't any better than the equivalent list comprehension.  For 3d or larger, it does condense the nest loops of a more explicit version - without saving time.
In the 2nd case, it iterates on the rows of (3,1):
In [35]: arr=np.asarray([[1,2,3]]).T; arr.shape
Out[35]: (3, 1)

In [36]: np.stack([foo(arr[i,:]) for i in range(3)], axis=0).shape
[1] [[2 3]
 [4 5]]
[2] [[3 4]
 [5 6]]
[3] [[4 5]
 [6 7]]
Out[36]: (3, 2, 2)

A row is (1,), added to (2,2) returns a (2,2).  Stack those 3 (2,2) on a new leading axis to make (3,2,2)

thank you for your answer! Can you please clarify exactly why in the 1st case the axis with 3 elements is trailing and in the second case it's leading?

In the first the input is (2,3), it iterates on axis 1 (3 times), passing 1d 'rows' to the function.  The function returns a (2,2), so the result is (2,2,3).  The 2 in (2,3) is replaced by (2,2).  In the 2nd, arr is (3,1), axis is 1.  Again it iterates 3 times, passing a (1,) to the function, which returns (2,2).  So the 1 is replaced by (2,2).  In both the 3 is the iteration axis, and retains is position relative to the new (2,2) result dimension.

Especially with 2d arrays, I think apply... is best understood by the equivalent list comprehension.  It is a python level iteration; nothing is compiled or speed up in C code.

not a definitive answer (i'm not really sure i understand your question), but a good hint i hope: i think your problem is more of a broadcasting problem than apply_along_axis one.
a good read often posted here is EricsBroadcastingDoc
we can emulate apply_along_axis with pure addition just by following the broadcasting rule:

In order to broadcast, the size of the trailing axes for both arrays in an operation must either be the same size or one of them must be one.

in your first example, your first array is of shape (2.3), the second is (2,2) and the result (2,2,3). we just have to add a new trailing axis to the second array to get the final result.
in your second example, your first array is of shape (3,1), the second is still (2,2) and the result (3,2,2). we have to add an axis to the first array to get the final result
import numpy as np

arr1=np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
arr2=np.array([[1,2,3]]).T
add_array=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

add_array2=add_array[:,:,np.newaxis]
print(arr1+add_array2)

arr4=arr2[:,:,np.newaxis]
print(arr4+add_array)

